# How do I delete text between 2 characters?

Tags: notepad++

For example I have:

```
Apple:123456789:pear
watermelon:57952161354:kfc
```

How do I delete the text that's between the ":" to get this:

```
Apple:apple
watermelon:kfc
```

Answer (score 25):

#### How do I replace all text between 2 `:`s with a single `:`?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `:.*?:`
- Set "Replace with" to `:`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

**Before**:

```
Apple:123456789:pear 
watermelon:57952161354:kfc
```

**After**:

```
Apple:pear 
watermelon:kfc
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: I would say that `:[^:]++:` would be much more efficient  - but that only really  matters if the text file is large. You could also try replacing `:[^:]++(?=:)` with the empty string - but I'm not sure if notepad supports lookaround.